# Creating new pandas dataframe after performing complex function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have trajectory data in following df:

```
   vid        points
0   0        [[2,4], [5,6], [8,9]]
1   1        [[10,11], [12,13], [14,15]]
2   2        [[1,2], [3,4], [8,1]]
3   3        [[21,10], [8,8], [4,3]]
4   4        [[15,2], [16,1], [17,3]]
```

each trajectory is a list points, identified by the vid.

I have a function, which calculates distance between two trajectories, let that distance function be method_dist(x, y) ; x,y are the two trajs.

This is how the method works:

```
x = df.iloc[0]["points"].tolist()
y = df.iloc[3]["points"].tolist()

method_dist(x, y)
```

Now, the method_dist will calculate the distance between the trajectories at index 0 and index 3 (not vid).

Since there are 100's of rows in my df, I want to automate this process if possible.

If I give a list of indices [0, 1, 3],
I want to create a function or loop where it calculates distance between trajectories at index 0 and index 1; then for index 0 and 3, then 1 and 3; until distance between every pair has been calculated, and I want to store the dist in a df2 as below:

**Note** we are not calculating distance between points anywhere, each cell under "points" is one whole trajectory, the function method_dist is calculating the dist between the whole trajectories.

```
     traj1_idx       traj2_idx        distance
  0    0             1                some_val
  1    0             3                some_val
  2    1             3                some_val
```

OR, even if I have to calculate the distance between a pair manually, I want to create a new df which atleast keeps appending the distance calculated and the pair of trajectory in the new df every time I take two trajectories.

Please let me know how to get the expected result or if I need to alter anything.

Thanks

Comment: I'm cooking up something fun

Comment: Thanks a tonnnn, wish I had your brain.

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom `class` where you define subtraction as `method_dist`

```
def method_dist(x, y):
    return abs(x - y)

class Trajectory(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.data = np.asarray(a)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return method_dist(self.data, other.data)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '☺ {}'.format(self.data.shape)
```

Then create a series of these things

```
s = df.points.apply(Trajectory)
s

0    ☺ (3, 2)
1    ☺ (3, 2)
2    ☺ (3, 2)
3    ☺ (3, 2)
4    ☺ (3, 2)
Name: points, dtype: object
```

Define a handy function to automate the different combination of differences

```
def get_combo_diffs(a, idx):
    """`a` is an array of Trajectory objects.  The return
    statement shows a slice of `a` minus another slice of `a`.
    numpy will execute the underlying objects __sub__ method
    for each pair and return an array of the results."""

    # this bit just finds all combinations of 2 at a time from `idx`
    idx = np.asarray(idx)
    n = idx.size
    i, j = np.triu_indices(n, 1)

    return a[idx[i]] - a[idx[j]]
```

Then use it...

```
get_combo_diffs(s.values, [0, 1, 3])

array([array([[8, 7],
       [7, 7],
       [6, 6]]),
       array([[19,  6],
       [ 3,  2],
       [ 4,  6]]),
       array([[11,  1],
       [ 4,  5],
       [10, 12]])], dtype=object)
```

That first element

get_combo_diffs(s.values, [0, 1, 3])

```
array([[8, 7], [7, 7], [6, 6]])
```

Is the result of either

```
first = np.array([[2, 4], [5, 6], [8, 9]])
second = np.array([[10, 11], [12, 13], [14, 15]])

method_dist(first, second)

array([[8, 7],
       [7, 7],
       [6, 6]])
```

Or equivalently

```
x, y = s.loc[0], s.loc[1]
x - y

array([[8, 7],
       [7, 7],
       [6, 6]])
```

Comment: I am not sure what the code is doing,  are you considering the distance between every pair of points in a single row?